# Array diff problem with one array contains null, and other empty values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel. I have 2 arrays. For example

```
$array1 = [
    'test1',
    '',
    'test2',
    'test3',
    '',
    'test4',
    '',
];

$array2 = [
    null
];

dd(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

result is

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "test1"
  2 => "test2"
  3 => "test3"
  5 => "test4"
]
```

but I expected

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "test1"
  1 => ""
  2 => "test2"
  3 => "test3"
  4 => ""
  5 => "test4"
  6 => ""
]
```

Can you ask why in array_diff considered `null is equal ''`, and how can I fix it without any additional cods. Now I solved this

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $array2, true)) {
        unset($array1[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-notes):

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In other words: when the string representation is the same.

So, your `null` value is casted to empty string, that's why you get your result. So, you can't solve your task **without** additional codes.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what was said you can easily filter them out with this

```
$array2 = array_filter($array2, function($v){
    return !is_null($v);
});
```

Comment: You suggested solution this case good (upvote). I change your solution to this `array_filter($array1, function($value) use ($array2)  {
                    return !in_array($value, $array2, true);
                });`  but my question properly answered by @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_udiff instead of array_diff.

```
array_udiff($array1, $array2, function ($a, $b) { return $a !== $b; })
```